# I need a simple command line program to transform XML using an XSL Stylesheet

Tags: java, python, xml, macos, xslt

I am on OSX Snow Leopard (10.6.2) I can install anything I need to. I would preferably like a Python or Java solution. I have searched on Google and found lots of information on writing my own program to do this, but this is a just a quick and dirty experiment so I don't want to invest a lot of time on writing a bunch of code to do this, I am sure someone else has done this already.

*This is off-topic now, do not use this question as an example of why your recommendations request is on topic, it is not. I apologize, but my Google-Foo was failing me the day I asked this 4 years ago!*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried '*xsltproc*'? It's probably already installed.

http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html

Comment: you are right OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.2 already has this installed, so it gets the check mark!

Comment: `xsltproc stylesheet file` outputs to stdout. Awesome.

Comment: Unfortunately `xsltproc` does not work with XSLT 2.0 as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 17):

I'd recommend [Saxon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/), which can be run from the command line like so:

```
java -jar /path/to/saxon.jar xmlfile xslfile
```

Comment: Add the -o argument to create an outputfile. `java -jar </path/to/saxon.jar> <xmlfile> <xslfile> -o:</path/to/outputfile.fo>`

Comment: Awesome, `saxon.jar` works with XSLT 2.0!

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (an XML command line toolset) ? It does lots of XML-related querying transformation, and in particular:

```
xml tr --help
XMLStarlet Toolkit: Transform XML document(s) using XSLT
Usage: xml tr [<options>] <xsl-file> {-p|-s <name>=<value>} [ <xml-file-or-uri> ... ]
where
   <xsl-file>      - main XSLT stylesheet for transformation
   <xml-file>      - input XML document file name (stdin is used if missing)
   <name>=<value>  - name and value of the parameter passed to XSLT processor
   -p              - parameter is XPATH expression ("'string'" to quote string)
   -s              - parameter is a string literal
```

Further documentation [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt).

Answer (score 4):

If I assume correctly that you want to supply a stylesheet and an XML document then Xalan-J has a command line feature you can use to do this:

http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html

which can be invoked with:

```
java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN foo.xml -XSL foo.xsl -OUT foo.out
```

Answer (score 3):

http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/

Answer (score 3):

Use [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/). It is very easy to use and very fast. It can work with XPath and includes a [XSLT transformer](http://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html#xslt).

Answer (score 0):

I have used Saxon 6.5 for years for command line transformations.  (Java, XSLT 1)

An excellent fallback if a native solution is not available.

Answer (score 0):

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9756520/520567) for another solution with com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Transform. But I noticed some weirdness with namespaces compared to xalan processing. Be aware behavior might be non standard.

Also you know, internal java classes are not good to rely on.