# Java Command Line XSLT Transformation in java

Tags: java, xslt, xml-parsing

I compile my style sheet with this command :

**C:\java -cp E:\ com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Compile -j E:\mysqldump-xml-to-sql E:\mysqldump-xml-to-sql-xsl**

this command work very well.  and I use another command for translate the test.xml file to result (xml, or any text format for example .sql). command is :

**java com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.Transform test.xml mysqldump_xml_to-sql_xsl**

But I can not pass any argument to this command for example classpaht. because I want to use this command in my java swing application  an need to pass argument to commandline.
How to get result from command line and store as output file.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to get result from command line and store as output file."

Just use the '>' operator to redirect the output to a text file.

"But I can not pass any argument to this command for example classpaht"

Why cant you pass any argument? Do you get any error?

Comment: MerC sachinrahulsourav
but I receive another error :
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError heap size error.  because I use a large xml file about 180m . can you help me :( .

Comment: Try increasing JVM memory set it to 1GB using java -Xmx1024m