# Automatic XSL generation from dynamically generated XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Is it possible to automatically generate xsl from dynamically generated xml in java if I don't know the structure of the xml in advance?

I know what tags can be there, but I can't know for sure which ones will be there.

Is such a thing even possible? :>

Comment: You can use a stylesheet containing an *identity transformation*, which will copy the source to the result tree. And you can write templates for the tags you know that are there, containing `apply-templates`, since if they aren't, the templates will simply not get called, but the processing will continue down to the other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use Saxon for java:

[I need a simple command line program to transform XML using an XSL Stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526681/i-need-a-simple-command-line-program-to-transform-xml-using-an-xsl-stylesheet)

From windows you could use xsd:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx