# Simple XSL saxon transform

Tags: java, xml, xslt, classpath, saxon

What's the [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2526681/262852) syntax for the transform?

```
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ 
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ java -cp /usr/share/java/Saxon-HE.jar  -xsl:w3.transform.xslt w3.data.xml
Unrecognized option: -xsl:w3.transform.xslt
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ 
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ cat w3.data.xml 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Eros</title>
    <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>BMG</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>One night only</title>
    <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1998</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
    <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS</company>
    <price>8.10</price>
    <year>1973</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Maggie May</title>
    <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Pickwick</company>
    <price>8.50</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Romanza</title>
    <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>10.80</price>
    <year>1996</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
    <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Atlantic</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Black angel</title>
    <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Mega</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
    <artist>Many</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Grammy</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1999</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>For the good times</title>
    <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Mucik Master</company>
    <price>8.70</price>
    <year>1995</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Big Willie style</title>
    <artist>Will Smith</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
    <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Polydor</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1971</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Soulsville</title>
    <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
    <country>Norway</country>
    <company>WEA</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1996</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>The very best of</title>
    <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Island</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Stop</title>
    <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>A and M</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
    <artist>T`Pau</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Siren</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Private Dancer</title>
    <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Capitol</company>
    <price>8.90</price>
    <year>1983</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Midt om natten</title>
    <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Medley</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1983</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
    <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>DECCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1991</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>The dock of the bay</title>
    <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Stax Records</company>
    <price>7.90</price>
    <year>1968</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Picture book</title>
    <artist>Simply Red</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
    <company>Elektra</company>
    <price>7.20</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Red</title>
    <artist>The Communards</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>London</company>
    <price>7.80</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Unchain my heart</title>
    <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>EMI</company>
    <price>8.20</price>
    <year>1987</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>



thufir@dur:~/saxon$ 
thufir@dur:~/saxon$ cat w3.transform.xslt 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
  Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>



thufir@dur:~/saxon$
```

Which `Java` class is [used](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_apply) for the data and `XSLT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Saxon Documentation](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/using-xsl/commandline.html), the command line is:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:source -xsl:stylesheet -o:output
```

Applied to your example:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/Saxon-HE.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:w3.data.xml -xsl:w3.transform.xslt -o:out.fo
```

Or, even simpler:

```
java -jar /usr/share/java/Saxon-HE.jar -s:w3.data.xml -xsl:w3.transform.xslt -o:out.fo
```

Comment: Note also that the Saxon documentation generally assumes you are familiar with how to run Java applications. If that's not the case, then you should also see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

For processing an XSLT file with Saxon, you do not need to specify a certain class. This is only necessary for XQuery requests. So use

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:XSLTFILE.xslt XMLFILE.xml
```

to process an XSLT file with a current version of Saxon.

Comment: More specifically (and this is imposed by Java, not by Saxon): if you use `-cp saxon9he.jar` then you must specify the entry point (`net.sf.saxon.Transform` or `net.sf.saxon.Query`) while if you use `-jar saxon9he.jar`, Java will use the default entry point `net.sf.saxon.Transform`.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. It is probably better than both of the answers.